# How to keep random walk scenario from going outside graphics window

Tags: python, graphics

I have created a random walk scenario where it takes one step in a random direction for a specific number of times. The one thing that I have run in to is that sometimes it will go off of the graphics window that I have set up and I can no longer see where it is at. 
Here is the code:

```
from random import *
from graphics import *
from math import *

def walker():
    win = GraphWin('Random Walk', 800, 800)
    win.setCoords(-50, -50, 50, 50)
    center = Point(0, 0)
    x = center.getX()
    y = center.getY()

while True:
    try:
        steps = int(input('How many steps do you want to take? (Positive integer only) '))
        if steps > 0:
            break
        else:
            print('Please enter a positive number')
    except ValueError:
        print('ERROR... Try again')

for i in range(steps):
    angle = random() * 2 * pi
    newX = x + cos(angle)
    newY = y + sin(angle)
    newpoint = Point(newX, newY).draw(win)
    Line(Point(x, y), newpoint).draw(win)
    x = newX
    y = newY

walker()
```

My question is, Is there a way that I can set parameters on the graphics window so that the walker can not go outside the window? And if it tries to, it would just turn around and try another direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try defining upper and lower bounds for x and y. Then use a while loop that keeps trying random points until the next one is in bounds.

```
from random import *
from graphics import *
from math import *

def walker():
    win = GraphWin('Random Walk', 800, 800)
    win.setCoords(-50, -50, 50, 50)
    center = Point(0, 0)
    x = center.getX()
    y = center.getY()

while True:
    try:
        steps = int(input('How many steps do you want to take? (Positive integer only) '))
        if steps > 0:
            break
        else:
            print('Please enter a positive number')
    except ValueError:
        print('ERROR... Try again')

# set upper and lower bounds for next point
upper_X_bound = 50.0
lower_X_bound = -50.0
upper_Y_bound = 50.0
lower_Y_bound = -50.0
for i in range(steps):
    point_drawn = 0 # initialize point not drawn yet
    while point_drawn == 0: # do until point is drawn
        drawpoint = 1 # assume in bounds
        angle = random() * 2 * pi
        newX = x + cos(angle)
        newY = y + sin(angle)
        if newX > upper_X_bound or newX < lower_X_bound:
            drawpoint = 0 # do not draw, x out of bounds
        if newY > upper_Y_bound or newY < lower_Y_bound:
            drawpoint = 0 # do not draw, y out of bounds
        if drawpoint == 1: # only draw points that are in bounds
            newpoint = Point(newX, newY).draw(win)
            Line(Point(x, y), newpoint).draw(win)
            x = newX
            y = newY
            point_drawn = 1 # set this to exit while loop

walker()
```